# How To Pick Out Activity inbetween phrases in DialogFlow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm trying to make a simple bot with Dialog flow to remind me to update my calendar with what I did during the day.

I want it to go something like this:

```
Bot: Hey, what did you do from 2pm-5pm today?
User: I did jogging from 2pm-3pm
Bot: Added "Jogging" to your calendar from 2pm-3pm. What about from 3pm-5pm?
User: I did reading.
Bot: Added "reading" from 3pm-5pm to your calendar.
```

My question is, how do I extract the activity (such as jogging or reading) as it can be literally anything. I guess I need to identify the "I did" part and see what it is after that and before "from 2-pm-3pm" part. I have an idea how to do this with Python, but I'm wondering if it's possible using DialogFlow?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the `@sys.any` entity type and assign it to that part of the training phrases that you're setting up in Dialogflow.

As you're setting up the training phrases, keep in mind that there may be many ways to say the same sort of thing, which is why using Dialogflow's training phrases are better than trying to capture parameters using string parsing.

So perhaps you want something like this

[image]

Comment: there would be some extra logic as well to prompt for whole day until all day activity is captured

Comment: Thank you so much!